# refer variable in host file from jinja2

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am using jinja2 template for haproxy configuration and I have variable declared in inventory file. how do I refer this variable in template. i have paste below script but it is not working.

My Inventory:-

```
[as]
10.0.0.1 asRole=batch
10.0.0.2 asRole=batch
10.0.0.3 asRole=transaction
10.0.0.4 asRole=transaction

[hap]
10.0.0.6
```

[hap] is the ip for the haproxy and my ansible is to set the haproxy configuration on [hap] node based on the [as] node.

My Jinja2 tempalte:-

```
{% for host in groups['as'] %}                                                 
 {% if "transaction" in "{{ asRole }} %}                                
  server {{ hostvars[host]['inventory_hostname'] }} {{ host }}:{{ httpd_port }}check
 {% endif %}                                                                     
{% endfor %}
```

Br,
Tanmoy

Comment: You can't nest Jinja demarkations - no `{{...}}` inside other `{{}}` or `{%...%}`. etc. So `{{ not someBool }}` works, but `{{ not {{ someBool }} }}` does not.

Comment: variable asRole is define in hosts file along the server IP and based on that I have to configure the haproxy. how to solve this?

Comment: Did you aaply the fix suggested below? (will edit above)

Comment: yes if I do not put {{ }} braces around the variable it throws error.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with the `asRole` Var:

```
{% for host in groups['as'] %}
 {% if "transaction" in asRole %}
  server {{ hostvars[host]['inventory_hostname'] }} {{ host }}:{{ httpd_port }}check
 {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: my jinja2 is not returning expected result. how to use the asRole variable in jinja2 so that i can get the expected result?

Comment: if i do not use {{ }} brakets around asRole then it throws error. how to solve this thing

Comment: [as]
10.0.0.1 asRole=batch
10.0.0.2 asRole=batch
10.0.0.3 asRole=transaction
10.0.0.4 asRole=transaction

[hap]
10.0.0.6 

my host file is like above and i am running hap host which is haproxy role setting for application server